# Defining DataFrame Schema for a table with 1500 columns in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with around 1500 columns in SQL Server. I need to read the data from this table and then convert it to proper datatype format and then insert the records into Oracle DB.

What is the best way to define the schema for this type of table with more than 1500 columns in a table. Is there any other option than hard coding the column names along with the datatypes?

1. Using `Case class`
2. Using `StructType`.

Spark Version used is 1.4

Comment: Many thanks @RamGhadiyaram. I will check the approach and get back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***For this type of requirements. I'd offer `case` class approach to prepare a dataframe***

Yes, There are some limitations like productarity  but we can overcome... 
you can do like below example for < versions 2.11 :

prepare a case class which `extends Product` and overrides methods.

like...

- `productArity():Int:` This returns the size of the attributes. In our case, it's 33. So, our implementation looks like this:
- `productElement(n:Int):Any:` Given an index, this returns the attribute. As protection, we also have a default case, which throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception:
- `canEqual (that:Any):Boolean`: This is the last of the three functions, and it serves as a boundary condition when an equality check is being done against class:

---

- Example implementation you can refer [this Student case class which has 33 fields in it](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big-data-and-business-intelligence/9781784396749/3/ch03lvl1sec22/loading-more-than-22-features-into-classes)
- Example [student dataset description here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance)

#### Another option :

Use the `StructType` to define the schema and create the dataframe.(if you don't want to use [spark csv api](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv))

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the suggestions. I am using scala 2.11.6 so 22 fields in case classes may not be an issue. So i think using Spark-Csv package would be better?

Answer (score 3):

The options for reading a table with 1500 columns

> 1) Using Case class

Case class would not work because its limited to 22 fields( for scala version < 2.11).

> 2) Using StructType

You can use the StructType to define the schema and create the dataframe.

**Third option**

You can use the [Spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) package . In this, you can use `.option("inferschema","true")`. This will automatically read the schema from the file.

Comment: productrity=22 issue was resolved in scala 2.11. For old versions it was the case which you mentioned.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram yeah Ram you are right. Have updated the answer. Actually i had answered on the basis of the spark version mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes Ram. The 22 limit for case class is solved in scala 2.11 So you suggest to use the Spark-csv package for defining the schema or any other better approach?

Comment: @SandeepShetty If you have 1500 columns, its better to use spark-csv package as it would directly create the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your schema with hundreds of columns in the json format. And then you can read this json file to construct you custom schema.

For example, 
Your schema json be:

```
[
    {
        "columnType": "VARCHAR",
        "columnName": "NAME",
        "nullable": true
    },
    {
        "columnType": "VARCHAR",
        "columnName": "AGE",
        "nullable": true
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Now you can read the the json to parse it to some case class to form the StructType.

```
case class Field(name: String, dataType: String, nullable: Boolean)
```

You can create a Map to have spark DataTypes corresponding to column Type Oracle string in json schema.

```
val dataType = Map(
   "VARCHAR" -> StringType,
   "NUMERIC" -> LongType,
   "TIMESTAMP" -> TimestampType,
   .
   .
   .
)

def parseJsonForSchema(jsonFilePath: String) = {
   val jsonString = Source.fromFile(jsonFilePath).mkString
   val parsedJson = parse(jsonString)
   val fields = parsedJson.extract[Field]
   val schemaColumns = fields.map(field => StructField(field.name, getDataType(field), field.nullable))
   StructType(schemaColumns)
}
```