# dataframe too many arguments in the rdd object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I tryed to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383578/how-to-convert-rdd-object-to-dataframe-in-spark) to convert rdd object to dataframe in spark. The class in my use case contains more than 100 arguments (columns)

```
case class MyClass(val1: String, ..., val104: String )

    val df = rdd.map({ 
      case Row(val1: String, ..., val104: String) => MyClass(val1, ..., val104)
    }).toDF("col1_name", ..., "col104_name")
```

I got this Error: *too many arguments for unapply pattern, maximum = 22*

May someone help me with a concrete example; i'm using spark 1.6 with scala .
Thank you

Comment: you can refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799147/defining-dataframe-schema-for-a-table-with-1500-columns-in-spark/41799237#41799237

Comment: I read that question but they require a csv file but i'm not using it; i'm using xl3 file

Comment: the problem with case class is that it has limitation of 22 fields in scala version < 2.11

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the limitation on case classes to 22 fields.

You need to define your case class as a more structured data type, so that there are only 22 top fields (but some of those may be case classes again).

Once you've done this, you can use your `Row` (which itself cannot be pattern matched with 104 fields, you will have to use `row(0), row(1), ..., row(103)`) to build your `MyClass`.